# How can I search all field in SOLR that contain the keywords,.?

Tags: solr, field

For example, I've keyword for search is: 'Basket Ball'. What is the query that can get all field that contain the 'Basket Ball',.?
I've tried to using *:Basket Ball, but it doesn't work,.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

schema.xml defines the default search field -

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

You can copy all the fields to this default search field.

```
<copyField source="field1" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="field2" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="field3" dest="text"/>
```

And query `q=basket ball` should work.

Comment: This is no longer true since Solr 3.6 and later. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2724

Answer (score 5):

The default search field (since 3.6) is now defined in solrconfig.xml

e.g. In the solrconfig.xml that ships with Solr configsets directory you will see something like

```
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">allText</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

You can change `allText` to `yourDefaultSearchFieldName`

Comment: after doing so, while searching giving error 'undefined field text'

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: i am using solr 5.3

Comment: In our configuration this is defined in solrconfig.xml  `<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">allText</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>` and the field 'allText' is defined in the schema.xml as follows `<field name="allText" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`
so my guess you need to define the appropriate field in the schema - in our case the field is called 'allText'

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a query parser which is able to dispatch tokens to several fields, such as (e)dismax. For exemple if you have two fields `field1` and `field2`: `http://solr/select?q={!dismax}Basket Ball&qf=field1^1 field2^1`

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29 for more information on dismax configuration.

Comment: if like that, it still must specify the fields that will be in search right,.? and what is the character ^1 mean,.?

Comment: Yes you need to specify every field. The '^' character gives you the ability to give weights to your field. For example, if a match in `field1` should be twice as important as a match in `field2`, you could use `qf=field1^2 field2^1`.