# Solr search in string

Tags: solr

I have field in docs :

```
<str name="ss_field_condition">new</str>
```

When I search with full string "new" I dont see this items.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/site/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=new&fq=&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=&debugQuery=on&explainOther=&hl.fl=
```

But I see many items when search with "ss_field_condition:new"

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/site/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=ss_field_condition%3Anew&fq=&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=&debugQuery=on&explainOther=&hl.fl=
```

As facet this field works well.

from schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

How I can enable search in this field? Version is 3.6.2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using `standard parser` since you didn't specify `defType` param in your url.

And you also didn't specify which field to search on, it will use a default field configured in `schema.xml`. Refer: [Set default search fields in Apache Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263663/set-default-search-fields-in-apache-solr)

If you want to search on specified field(s), here is a few example:

- search on `title` field:

  > q="+title:new"
- search on `title` field **or** `content` field, **either** match:

  > q="title:java content:java"
- search on `title` field **and** `content` field, **both** match:

  > q="title:java +content:java"

**More tips:**

- Solr is already in version 5.4.1, so try to upgrade your version if possible, there are huge changes since version 3.x, e.g `solr cloud`.
- The `edismax` parser is more powerful to use, you might want that.
- If you want to search on a fields, don't forget to index it, even for a string type.

Comment: Thanks!
How I can add all "string" fields automaticaly? I have big number of additional 'string' fields to include to search.

Comment: @AndreyKostromin refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927992/solr-set-fileds-as-default-search-field